# MvC5 Authorization / Roles with Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, iis, identity

Building an MVC5 intranet application that is using Windows Authentication.

I want to use the builtin roleManager to add roles to existing users.  If I attempt to create a user, say AD\Username and add him the to Admin user role, I can do this just fine and Asp .Net Identity builds out and stores that information in the database.

However, I using [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] on any particular controller action will not give me access to that page.  It's as if there is no link between AD\Username and my AD user.

Is this built in to work with Asp .Net Identity?  Or do I need to do some heavy customization?  This seems fairly straightforward.

Thanks for the help!